# How to specify in which order to load S4 methods when using roxygen2

Tags: r, documentation, package, r-s4, roxygen2

I ran into following problem already multiple times.

Say you have two classes, `classA` and `classB` described in the following files `classA.R` :

```
#' the class classA
#'
#' This is a class A blabla
#' \section{Slots}{\describe{\item{\code{A}}{a Character}}}
#' @ name classA
#' @rdname classA
#' @exportClass classA
setClass("classA",representation(A="character"))
```

And `classB.R`

```
#' the class classB
#'
#' This is a class B blabla
#' \section{Slots}{\describe{\item{\code{B}}{an object of class A}}}
#' @ name classB
#' @rdname classB
#' @exportClass classB
setClass("classB",representation(B="classA"))
```

I believed these files were read in alphabetical order by `roxygen2`, but that is not the case. If I try to build the package, I might get the following error:

```
roxygenize("./myExample")
Error in getClass(Class, where = topenv(parent.frame())) :
   "ClassA" is not a defined class
```

How can I make sure that `roxygenize()` knows in which order to read the files, i.e. which class definition should be read before the other?

---

Note : I know I answered my own question. That is because I ran into this problem rather often, and realized the proper way to do this after looking at the code of `roxygen2`. So for reference, here's my findings.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this:

As described in `?collate_roclet`, you can use the @include tag to specify which class should be read before which. In this case, you can add to the file `classB.r` the following line right before the actual R code:

```
#' @include classA.r
```

These tags are read specifically to update the `Collate` field in the `DESCRIPTION` file, and are the recommended way of dealing with the problem.

In some cases the dependencies might be so complex you want to keep an overview yourself and not rely completely on adding `@include` tags in your codebase. In that case you can just specify the `Collate` field at the end of the `DESCRIPTION` file, like this:

```
Package: myExample
Type: Package
...
Collate:
    'classA.R'
    'classB.R'
```

The function `roxygenize()` first checks the `DESCRIPTION` file, and loads whatever files are specified there first in the order they're specified. Only then the rest of the package is loaded.

Comment: @hadley As I wrote in my question, I tried the `@include` tag, and that one also merged the help files on the different classes (which was not my intention). It works fine using the Collate field, but I hope you find some time and inspiration to incorporate an elegant solution for this in the next version of roxygen.

Comment: `@include` shouldn't change anything apart from the collate. Can you provide a minimal reproducible example?

Comment: @hadley I can't reproduce anymore. I guess it had something to do with the naming I used (I might have used the same name twice). I update accordingly