# What's the recommended package build workflow with packages that contain S4 classes?

Tags: r, rstudio, r-s4, roxygen2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to properly document S4 class slots using Roxygen2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368262/how-to-properly-document-s4-class-slots-using-roxygen2)

I would like to build a package that contains `S4 classes` using R Studio and `roxygen2`. 
I had already documented all my functions using `roxygen2` syntax when I introduced a couple of `S4 classes` to my package.

Now I realized that there's no '@slot' functionality out-of-the-box. So I wonder how can I keep all my documentation work for the other functions and document the `S4 classes` manually like suggested in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7368262/how-to-properly-document-s4-class-slots-using-roxygen2)?

Or in other words which workflow would you recommend to built a package that contains both old school functions and `S4 classes`?

EDIT: Would you recommend to configure R Studio built tools not to create .Rd files. `roxygenize` manually and then add the info afterwards? Still this would lead to overwriting the manually generated .Rd files of the classes...

Comment: @Hans0I0 What exactly is your problem here? Do what is said in that thread you link to, and eg http://www.inside-r.org/questions/how-properly-document-s4-class-slots-using-roxygen2. Make sure you export them correctly.µ

Comment: My problem is the R Studio standard workflow. Everytime I hit build `Roxygen` is used to create .Rd files. If I add the .Rd files of the classes manually like suggested in this thread, next time I run build from R Studio these manual changes are overwritten.

Comment: But you don't have to add the .Rd files manually. You just have to use the describe to create your slots.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## General info on roxygen and S4 classes

The first version of roxygen had an `@slot` tag, but that version isn't maintained any more in favor of `roxygen2`. So it's advised against to use that old version.

As for now, `roxygen2` doesn't have real support for S4 classes. Hadley is working hard to make that happen in `roxygen3` (https://github.com/hadley/roxygen3). In case you want to give it a shot and feel brave: install `roxygen3` from github and try the development version. Note that this version eventually will be incoorporated into `roxygen2`, so in time the problem will solve itself.

## Regarding your workflow:

I personally always find it a bad idea to combine using roxygen and manually written .Rd files. But if you must, you can send the output of roxygen to a different directory using the argument `roxygen.dir`. This way you can copy whatever you want back into the package directory without overwriting the manually written files.

```
roxygenise("./mypackage", roxygen.dir="./myroxygendir")
```

What I would do, is simply use `roxygen2` to write the Rd files for your classes as explained in the thread you link to. You don't have to add them manually like you believe for some unknown reason. You just use the `#'` to indicate the Rd block like always, and use whatever is given in the thread you link to. If you want to make the slots a separate section, you can do that using the `@section` tag like in the example below.

An example of how to add Slots for the moment using `roxygen2` :

```
#' The MY class
#'
#' This class blabla yadayada
#'
#'@section Slots:
#'  \describe{
#'    \item{\code{aslot}:}{Object of class \code{"numeric"}, containing 
#'whatever and a bit more}
#'    \item{\code{anotherslot}:}{Object of class \code{"character"}, containing
#' strings.}
#'  }
#'
#' @note Yes, you can add notes
#' @name MY 
#' @rdname MY
#' @aliases MY-class
#' @exportClass MY
#' @author Joris Meys
setClass("MY",
         representation=representation(aslot="numeric",
                                       anotherslot="character"
                                       )
```

Comment: Definitely will check out roxygen3's dev version. Needless to say I am a big fan of Hadley's work. However, currently I just want to avoid a lack of focus finishing my package. Though I like both of your answers I can only +1 :) . I didn't realize before your comment that I can actually have \describe and @params in the same document. It throws a warning in R Studio but works. Thanks Joris!

Comment: @hans0l0 If you have an S4 class, I wonder why you need `@param` in the same document. Personally, I keep my class files separated from getters, setters and what-not. That's easier to keep an overview for me, and it doesn't give warnings in RStudio. Be sure to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13510234/how-to-specify-in-which-order-to-load-s4-methods-when-using-roxygen2 for use of the `@include` tag

Comment: You are right. I don't use no `@param`. just meant to say I did not know I could combine the @ syntax with `\describe`. Ah and thx for the link – indeed very educating...